# How can we form normative value judgement about technology without knowing all the use cases of technology?

Tags: philosophy-of-technology, normativity

It makes sense to define a normative value system for "axiomatic" values. For example that all humans should have the same rights.

However when it comes to technology I fail to see how it is possible to form normative values about which technology should be researched and which shouldn't. I doubt that this is even possible since that would mean knowing all possible use cases of technology beforehand. (and further technologies depending on the initial technology)

Comment: The same way we have a normative system for human behavior without knowing all possible cases of human behavior. We regulate what we do know, and make adjustments as we go along. That's also the same way we have a system of physical laws without knowing all possible cases of physical behavior. We do not need to know everything to know something, or make decisions based on that much.

Comment: Research for gaining understanding in itself seems never bad, it is the method of research that may be problematic in such cases.  Development however is for specific use cases.